# OrmLite: выборка в foregin collection

Tags: orm, java

Есть такая вот структура двух табличек:

```
public class A {
    public long id;
    public Collection<B> b;
}

public class B {
    public long id;
    public boolean enabled;
    public A a;
}
```

Как мне получить все A, у которых бы в списках b значения полей были бы только enabled = true?
Перечитал все доки Ormlite, но ничего по этому поводу не нашел, гугление дало тот же результат. Заранее спасибо.